# can't post form data as json using jquery 3 to jersey

Tags: jquery, post, jersey, form-submit

I need to understand why my $.ajax is not sending a POST but instead a GET to jersey?

I have seen many posts in stackoverflow and other websites/forums with no success.

this is my client code:

```
$('#formLookupUser').submit( function (event) {

        var userFilter = {
            "email" : $('#inputEmail').val(),
            "firstName" :$('#inputFirstName').val(),
            "lastName" : $('#inputLastName').val(),
            "type" : $('#inputType').val()
        };

        $.ajax( {
            method: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/newjersey/rest/user/filter",
            data: JSON.stringify(userFilter),
            contentType: "application/json"
        } )
        .done( function(response){
            showResults(response);
        })
        .fail( function(jqXHR, textStatus){
            alert(textStatus);
        });
});
```

and this is my server code:

```
@POST
@Path("/add")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addUser(User user) throws SQLException {

    logger.info("Inserting user ... ");

    try{
        DBQueries q = new DBQueries();

        int idUser = q.insUserAndBankDetails(user);
        user.setId(idUser);

        return Response.ok("User successfully saved").build();

    }catch (SQLException e){
        return Response.serverError().entity(e).build();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The url and parameter names in your screenshot don't match your code snippet...

Comment: You aren't preventing the default action in your submit handler, maybe that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working following @JasonP suggestion.

The problem was that the form was submitting its data before my $.ajax call.

the solution is to change the client as:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#formLookupUser').submit( function (event) {

        clearResults();

        var userFilter = {
            "email" : $('#inputEmail').val(),
            "firstName" :$('#inputFirstName').val(),
            "lastName" : $('#inputLastName').val(),
            "type" : $('#inputType').val()
        };

        $.ajax( {
            method: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/newjersey/rest/user/filter",
            data: JSON.stringify(userFilter),
            contentType: "application/json"
        } )
        .done( function(response){
            showResults(response);
        })
        .fail( function(jqXHR, textStatus){
            alert(textStatus);
        });

        event.preventDefault(); // <--- Prevent Default action.
    });
```